# Google translate widget - customizing the look

Tags: google-translate, customizing

I have this code on my website to add translate widget:

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/translatemypage.xml&up_source_language=pl&w=160&h=60&title=&border=&output=js"></script>
```

How can I customize the look of this widget?